# Conditional probability expression in restricted boltzmann machine? How to get p(h=1|v)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, maximum-likelihood, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I'm reading a book on Deep learning and having trouble in deriving an expression
[image]

[image]

Can someone please explain how to go from equation(20.10) to (20.11)? How summation term is converting into product term?

Answer (score 2):

$\exp(a+b)=\exp(a)\exp(b)$. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes and whai if we have to calculatep(h=1|v)? I mean which parameters will change?

Comment: Well just plug in $h=1$ (note that $h$ is actually a vector) and $v=v$ and that will give you $P(h=1|v)$.

Comment: Can you please explain why they have omitted summation sign while moving from (20.10) to (20.11)? what will be its physical meaning?

Comment: $\exp(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)=\prod_{i=1}^n\exp(a_i)$. Again, this follows from the fact that exponentials are multiplicative.